# Java/FX and Scenebuilder; collision detection and stopping movement

Tags: java, oop, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm a beginner with java and OOP and I'm trying to create a maze game and currently I'm using an animation timer so that the player moves smoothly. I created a collision detection method that returns true when the player encounters an unbreakable wall and prints out that there is a collision, but the player continues moving over it. Need help and suggestions, thanks!

This is my player class

```
package application;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.beans.binding.BooleanBinding;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public class Player{
    @FXML private ImageView player;
    @FXML AnchorPane scene;
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private int lives;
    private int scoreCounter;
    private BooleanProperty upPressed = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    private BooleanProperty leftPressed = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    private BooleanProperty rightPressed = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    private BooleanProperty downPressed = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    
    private BooleanBinding keyPressed = upPressed.or(leftPressed).or(rightPressed).or(downPressed);
    
    private boolean left, up, right, down;
    boolean canMove = true;
    
    private double movementVariable = 0.75;
    
    CollisionHandler collisionHandler = new CollisionHandler();

        
    public Player(ImageView player, double x, double y, int lives, int scoreCounter) {
        this.player = player;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.lives = lives;
        this.scoreCounter = scoreCounter;
    }
    
 
    public void makeMovable(ImageView player, AnchorPane scene, ArrayList<Rectangle> unbreakableObjects) {
        this.player = player;
        this.scene = scene;
        
        movementSetup();
        
        keyPressed.addListener(((observableValue, aBoolean, t1) -> {
            if (!aBoolean) {
                timer.start();
                canMove = false;
            } else {
                timer.stop();
            }
        }));
    }
    
    AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
//      double currentX = player.getLayoutX();
//      double currentY = player.getLayoutY();
//      
        @Override
        public void handle(long timestamp) {
//          double currentX = player.getLayoutX();
//          double currrentY = player.getLayoutY();
            if(upPressed.get()) {
                player.setLayoutY(player.getLayoutY() - movementVariable);
            }
            if(downPressed.get()){
                player.setLayoutY(player.getLayoutY() + movementVariable);
            }
            if(leftPressed.get()){
                player.setLayoutX(player.getLayoutX() - movementVariable);
            }
            if(rightPressed.get()){
                player.setLayoutX(player.getLayoutX() + movementVariable);
            }
            
        }
    };
    
    public boolean playerCollidesWithUnbreakable(double x, double y, ArrayList <Rectangle> unbreakables) {
        if (collisionHandler.checkCollisionUnbreakables(this, unbreakables)) {
            if(upPressed.get()) {
                player.setLayoutY(player.getLayoutY() + movementVariable);
            }
            if(downPressed.get()){
                player.setLayoutY(player.getLayoutY() - movementVariable);
            }
            if(leftPressed.get()){
                player.setLayoutX(player.getLayoutX() + movementVariable);
            }
            if(rightPressed.get()){
                player.setLayoutX(player.getLayoutX() - movementVariable);
            }
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
    }
    
    private void movementSetup(){
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.W) {
                upPressed.set(true);
                up = true;
            }
            if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.A) {
                leftPressed.set(true);
                left = true;
            }
            if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.S) {
                downPressed.set(true);
                down = true;
            }
            if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.D) {
                rightPressed.set(true);
                right = true;
            }
        });
        scene.setOnKeyReleased(e ->{
            if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.W) {
                upPressed.set(false);
                up = true;
            }
            if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.A) {
                leftPressed.set(false);
                left = true;
            }
            if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.S) {
                downPressed.set(false);
                down = true;
            }
            if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.D) {
                rightPressed.set(false);
                right = true;
            }
        });
    }
    public int getScore() {
            return this.scoreCounter;
    }
    
    public void incrementScore() {
            this.scoreCounter++;
    }
    
    public double returnX() {
            return player.getX();
    }
    
    public double returnY() {
            return player.getY();
    }
    
    public void newX(double x) {
            player.setX(x);
    }
    
    public void newY(double y) {
            player.setY(y);
    }
    
    public Bounds getPlayerBounds() {
        return player.getBoundsInParent();
    }

  
    public ImageView getPlayerImageView() {
        return player;
    }

}
```

This is my controller class

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;


public class PlayerController implements Initializable{
    
    @FXML
    private ImageView player;
    private Player playerComponent;
    
    @FXML private AnchorPane scene;
    
    
    private double x = 0;
    private double y = 0;
    private int scoreCounter = 0;
    
    @FXML private int lives;
    @FXML private Text score;
    
    @FXML private Rectangle Bed;
    @FXML private Rectangle Plant;
    @FXML private Rectangle Shelf1;
    @FXML private Rectangle Shelf2;
    @FXML private Rectangle Box1;
    @FXML private Rectangle Box2;
    @FXML private Rectangle Box3;
    @FXML private Rectangle Box4;
    @FXML private Rectangle Cabinet1;
    @FXML private Rectangle TVset;
    @FXML private Rectangle chair1;
    @FXML private Rectangle chair2;
    @FXML private Rectangle Table1;
    @FXML private Rectangle Desk1;
    @FXML private Rectangle Desk2;
    @FXML private Rectangle Box5;
    @FXML private Rectangle Box6;
    @FXML private Rectangle Cabinet2;
    @FXML private Rectangle RightWall;
    @FXML private Rectangle TopWall;
    @FXML private Rectangle LeftWall;
    @FXML private Rectangle BottomWall;
    
    @FXML private ImageView breakable1;
    @FXML private ImageView breakable2;
    @FXML private ImageView breakable3;
    @FXML private ImageView breakable4;
    @FXML private ImageView breakable5;
    @FXML private ImageView breakable6;
    @FXML private ImageView breakable7;
    @FXML private ImageView breakable8;
    @FXML private ImageView breakable9;
    @FXML private ImageView breakable10;
    @FXML private ImageView breakable11;
    @FXML private ImageView breakable12;
    @FXML private ImageView breakable13;
    @FXML private ImageView breakable14;
    @FXML private ImageView breakable15;
    @FXML private ImageView breakable16;
    @FXML private ImageView breakable17;
    @FXML private ImageView breakable18;
    @FXML private ImageView breakable19;
    @FXML private ImageView breakable20;
    @FXML private ImageView breakable21;
    @FXML private ImageView breakable22;
    @FXML private ImageView breakable23;
    @FXML private ImageView breakable24;

    private ArrayList<Rectangle> unbreakableObjects = new ArrayList();
    
    private ArrayList<ImageView> breakableObjects;
    
    Unbreakable unbreakable = new Unbreakable();
    
    CollisionHandler collisionHandler = new CollisionHandler();
    
    AnimationTimer gameLoop;
    
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        this.scene = scene;
        playerComponent = new Player(player, x, y, lives, scoreCounter);        
        gameLoop = new AnimationTimer() {

            @Override
            public void handle(long arg0) {
                double currentX = player.getX();
                double currentY = player.getY();
                
                playerComponent.makeMovable(player, scene, unbreakableObjects);
                if(collisionHandler.checkCollisionUnbreakables(playerComponent, unbreakableObjects)) {
                    player.setX(currentX);
                    player.setY(currentY);
                }
            
            }   
        };
                
        gameLoop.start();
        
        unbreakableObjects.add(Bed);
        unbreakableObjects.add(Cabinet1);
        unbreakableObjects.add(Shelf1);
        unbreakableObjects.add(Shelf2);
        unbreakableObjects.add(Box1);
        unbreakableObjects.add(Box2);
        unbreakableObjects.add(Box3);
        unbreakableObjects.add(Box4);
        unbreakableObjects.add(Plant);
        unbreakableObjects.add(TVset);
        unbreakableObjects.add(chair1);
        unbreakableObjects.add(chair2);
        unbreakableObjects.add(Table1);
        unbreakableObjects.add(Desk1);
        unbreakableObjects.add(Desk2);
        unbreakableObjects.add(Box5);
        unbreakableObjects.add(Box6);
        unbreakableObjects.add(Cabinet2);
        unbreakableObjects.add(RightWall);
        unbreakableObjects.add(TopWall);
        unbreakableObjects.add(LeftWall);
        unbreakableObjects.add(BottomWall);
        
        breakableObjects = new ArrayList<>();

        breakableObjects.add(breakable1);
        breakableObjects.add(breakable2);
        breakableObjects.add(breakable3);
        breakableObjects.add(breakable4);
        breakableObjects.add(breakable5);
        breakableObjects.add(breakable6);
        breakableObjects.add(breakable7);
        breakableObjects.add(breakable8);
        breakableObjects.add(breakable9);
        breakableObjects.add(breakable10);
        breakableObjects.add(breakable11);
        breakableObjects.add(breakable12);
        breakableObjects.add(breakable13);
        breakableObjects.add(breakable14);
        breakableObjects.add(breakable15);
        breakableObjects.add(breakable16);
        breakableObjects.add(breakable17);
        breakableObjects.add(breakable18);
        breakableObjects.add(breakable19);
        breakableObjects.add(breakable20);
        breakableObjects.add(breakable21);
        breakableObjects.add(breakable22);
        breakableObjects.add(breakable23);
        breakableObjects.add(breakable24);
    }
    
    
    private void pointChecker() {
        playerComponent.incrementScore();       score.setText(String.valueOf(playerComponent.getScore()));
        System.out.println("PLAYER SCORE: " + playerComponent.getScore());
        
    }
}
```

This is my collision handler

```
package application;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public class CollisionHandler {
    public boolean checkCollisionUnbreakables(Player player, ArrayList<Rectangle> unbreakableObjects) {
        Bounds playerBounds = player.getPlayerBounds();
        
        for (Rectangle rectangle : unbreakableObjects) {
                
            Bounds rectangleBounds = rectangle.getBoundsInParent();

            if (playerBounds.intersects(rectangleBounds)) {
                System.out.println("You can't go there!");
                return true;
            } 
        }
        return false;
    }
    public boolean checkCollisionBreakables(Player player, ArrayList<ImageView> breakableObjects) {
        Bounds playerBounds = player.getPlayerBounds();
        
        for (ImageView breakable : breakableObjects) {
            Bounds breakableBounds = breakable.getBoundsInParent();
            if (playerBounds.intersects(breakableBounds)) {
                if (breakable.getImage() == null) {
//                  System.out.println("Cleared already");
                    // Cleared already
                    return false;
                } else {

                    System.out.println("Picked up trash");
                breakable.setImage(null);
                return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Tried storing the current position of the player before moving and after moving I check for collisions and if there is a collision, I set the player to the stored position.

Comment: I am no expert at this, but I did create a pong game a while ago and I ran into a similar issue.  Here is what I think needs to happen when you detect a collision, find out how far past the entry point the colliding object goes. Move the colliding object back that distance. See `checkWallCollision` and `checkPaddleCollision` [here](https://github.com/sedj601/PongFX/blob/master/src/pongfx/FXMLDocumentController.java)

Comment: You may be interested in [FXGL](https://github.com/AlmasB/FXGL) for game creation.  Also a [simple breakout game](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/910dae32ef6d1bd4257850031aefcba2) you could take a loot at.  Also, you may wish to research [tile maps](https://www.mapeditor.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I saw some problems in your code.

1- In your Player class, the AnimationTimer updates the value of X and Y without checking with Collision Handler if it is allowed. So, it will get moving independently of any check. Create an atribute like "layoutX" and update it in Player, to separate the intended position and the actual position.

```
    AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
//      double currentX = player.getLayoutX();
//      double currentY = player.getLayoutY();
//      
        @Override
        public void handle(long timestamp) {
//          double currentX = player.getLayoutX();
//          double currrentY = player.getLayoutY();
            if(upPressed.get()) {
                player.setLayoutY(player.getLayoutY() - movementVariable);
            }
            if(downPressed.get()){
                player.setLayoutY(player.getLayoutY() + movementVariable);
            }
            if(leftPressed.get()){
                player.setLayoutX(player.getLayoutX() - movementVariable);
            }
            if(rightPressed.get()){
                player.setLayoutX(player.getLayoutX() + movementVariable);
            }
            
        }
    };
```

2- Change your PlayerController to something like that:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    this.scene = scene;
    playerComponent = new Player(player, x, y, lives, scoreCounter);        
    gameLoop = new AnimationTimer() {

        @Override
        public void handle(long arg0) {
            double currentX = player.getLayoutX();
            double currentY = player.getLayoutY();
            
            playerComponent.makeMovable(player, scene, unbreakableObjects);
            if(!collisionHandler.checkCollisionUnbreakables(playerComponent, unbreakableObjects)) {
                player.setX(currentX);
                player.setY(currentY);
            }
        
        }   
    };
```

So, separating x and layoutX will let you do the getLayoutX (the intended position). You also should put a negation "!" in the if, because you need to move when there is not an unbreakable, not when there is one.

Comment: Did it work? I saw an upvote, but I didn't get more feedback.

Answer (score -2):

Try breaking out the loop once a collision is detected.

```
public boolean checkCollisionUnbreakables(Player player, ArrayList<Rectangle> unbreakableObjects) {
    Bounds playerBounds = player.getPlayerBounds();
    Boolean collide = false;
    for (Rectangle rectangle : unbreakableObjects) {
            
        Bounds rectangleBounds = rectangle.getBoundsInParent();

        if (playerBounds.intersects(rectangleBounds)) {
            System.out.println("You can't go there!");
            collide = true;break;
        } 
    }
    return collide;
}
```

Your loop still continues to iterate through all the unbreakable objects and will return false if that unbreakable object isn't within the player bounds. Sure it will print out the warning but you didn't break the loop, resulting it to return all iterated results.

Comment: The current code returns when `intersects` returns true.  How does that allow the loop to continue?

Comment: You could place "return true" in the loop and "return false" at the end of the method. You do not need the variable.